# Reading data from Raspberry PI's uart

Tags: python, c++, linux, uart, raspberry-pi3

I am testing to read data from Raspberry PI's uart.
I have USB to UART adaptor and connect between PI's USB port and PI's UART (g, Rx,Tx). 
Then the code for the USB port run. The code sends data to uart at every 100msec.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
counter=0
while 1:
  print counter
  if counter>=1000:
      ser.write('\r')
  else:
       ser.write('%d \n'%(counter))
  time.sleep(0.1)//100msec
  counter += 1
```

Then at my UART side, the C++ program reads the data from UART.
The code is as follow and every 100ms I `call the ReadData_helper function using a timer`.

```
void InterfaceUART::PortInitialization()
{
        fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY ); 
     if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

     tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current serial port settings */
     bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio)); /* clear struct for new port settings */

        /* 
          BAUDRATE: Set bps rate. You could also use cfsetispeed and cfsetospeed.
          CRTSCTS : output hardware flow control (only used if the cable has
                    all necessary lines. See sect. 7 of Serial-HOWTO)
          CS8     : 8n1 (8bit,no parity,1 stopbit)
          CLOCAL  : local connection, no modem contol
          CREAD   : enable receiving characters
        */
         newtio.c_cflag = B9600 | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

        /*
          IGNPAR  : ignore bytes with parity errors
          ICRNL   : map CR to NL (otherwise a CR input on the other computer
                    will not terminate input)
          otherwise make device raw (no other input processing)
        */
         newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;

        /*
         Raw output.
        */
         newtio.c_oflag = 0;

        /*
          ICANON  : enable canonical input
          disable all echo functionality, and don't send signals to calling program
        */
         newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;

     /*set signal*/
         //saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
         //saio.sa_flags = 0;
         //saio.sa_restorer = NULL; 
         //sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

         fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);//|FASYNC//FNDELAY ,#FNDELAY makes read function to return with 0 if no characters are available on the port and if FNDELAY == 0, it is blocking mode
         fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());

    /* 
      initialize all control characters 
      default values can be found in /usr/include/termios.h, and are given
      in the comments, but we don't need them here
    */
     newtio.c_cc[VINTR]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-c */ 
     newtio.c_cc[VQUIT]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-\ */
     newtio.c_cc[VERASE]   = 0;     /* del */
     newtio.c_cc[VKILL]    = 0;     /* @ */
     newtio.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;     /* Ctrl-d */
     newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;     /* inter-character timer unused */
     newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;     /* blocking read until 1 character arrives */
     newtio.c_cc[VSWTC]    = 0;     /* '\0' */
     newtio.c_cc[VSTART]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-q */ 
     newtio.c_cc[VSTOP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-s */
     newtio.c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-z */
     newtio.c_cc[VEOL]     = 0;     /* '\0' */
     newtio.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;     /* Ctrl-r */
     newtio.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;     /* Ctrl-u */
     newtio.c_cc[VWERASE]  = 0;     /* Ctrl-w */
     newtio.c_cc[VLNEXT]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-v */
     newtio.c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;     /* '\0' */

    /* 
      now clean the modem line and activate the settings for the port
    */
     tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
     tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

        return;
}

void *InterfaceUART::ReadData(void *p){     
      //InterfaceUART *app = (InterfaceUART*)p;
      res = read(fd,buf,255); 
    //buf[res] = 0;    
      float *a = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
      *a = (float)atof(buf);
      //pthread_exit((void*)&a); //success
      return (void*)a;
}
void *InterfaceUART::ReadData_helper (void *p){
    InterfaceUART *app = (InterfaceUART*)p;
    return ((InterfaceUART*)p)->ReadData(app);
}
```

The interface works for sometime and after that same data is read repeatedly.

```
deg is : 0 speed is : 135
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 136
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 137
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 138
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 139
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 140
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 141
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 142
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 143
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 144
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 145
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 146
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 147
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 148
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 149
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 150
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 151
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 152
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 153
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 154
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 155
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 156
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 156
time diff 0
deg is : 0 speed is : 156
time diff 1
deg is : 0 speed is : 156
```

It reads till 155 correctly and at 156 , the data is repeatedly read.
156 is not fixed, it stops randomly sometimes 71, sometimes 153 etc. After reaching to a number and doesn't change anymore.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify something... Are you sending data via the rx/tx lines on the gpio pins to a usb to serial adapter. Where the usb to serial adapter is also plugin into the pi???

Comment: @bruffalobill the adaptor is plugged into one of the USB ports. The adaptor's TX goes to UART's RX (GPIO 10) and adaptor's RX goes to UART's TX (GPIO 8).

Comment: What is the output of your python program?? Can you rule out that as a point of failure? Also I am adding the python tag.

Comment: @bruffalobill Python works fine. Even the UART reading doesn't change, the python output is changing at least count is increased. Actual writing to the buffer, how to check? Then some more, it works only at Baudrate 9600. The other baudrate, reading from UART is 0. I found a few discussions to set core freq to 250, it does not work for my case.

Comment: @bruffalobill I tried to measure at adapter's TX pin at scope and bit patterns are changing so transmission side is ok but even UART reading is not  changed any more.